# Compound Statement Expression In C

Tags: c, syntax, initialization, expression, declaration

Below code is not working.

```
int i = {(void) 999; 100;};
```

Adding parentheses will work. WHY?

```
int i = ({(void) 999; 100;});
```

There is another way to do this type of assignment:

```
int i = ((void) 999, 100);
```

What make them different?

Comment: What do you think you're actually accomplishing with that?  Why would you not simply write `int i = 100;`? Or even `(void) 999; int i = 100;`?

Comment: (void) 999; is just an illusion of any statement, which can be meaningful in code context.

Comment: Yes, @Aison.  And?  The question remains: what do you think you are achieving by stuffing code into a variable's initializer that does not contribute to computing its initial value?  The second form I suggested in my previous comment, +/- the cast to `void`, would be far more appropriate if the `(void) 999;` must be executed instead of simply dropped.  That's in fact why I presented that alternative in the first place.

Comment: It does not have to be constant "100" assignment. The focus in this question is syntax. Replace "100" by a function that takes int x and return x. By stuffing, you can do something before the function call such as printing another variable's state when assigning.

Comment: think of an existing function `int getX(int x);` with no access to is implementation. 
`getX()` is called everywhere but you want to know the state of variable y every time `getX()` is called. 

"override" getX() by macro definition: 
` #define getX(x)    ((void) printf(y), (getX)(x))`

Comment: Well, that's at least plausible.  But if you are minded to play *Fun With Macros* then you would probably be better off to write a macro that interposes a wrapper function instead of a comma expression.

Comment: I use comma expression inside a Macro instead of wrapper function for reasons. For example, to use __FILE__, __LINE__ for debug. Imaging checking the variable state and making an assertion so that you know which file which line goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration

```
int i = {(void) 999; 100;};
```

there are used two statements inside the braces

```
(void) 999;
```

and

```
100;
```

as initializers.

This is syntactically invalid. To initialize a scalar object using a list enclosed in braces you may use only one assignment expression and neither  statements.

This construction

```
int i = ({(void) 999; 100;});
```

is also an invalid C construction. However a compound statement enclosed in parentheses may appear as an expression in GNU C. It is its own language extension. The value of the expression is 100. That is the variable i is initialized by the value 100.

This declaration

```
int i = ((void) 999, 100);
```

is the only valid C construction. Within the parentheses there is used the comma operator. The value of the expression is the right most operand of the expression that is 100.

In fact the last declaration is equivalent to

```
int i = 100;
```

The compiler should issue a warning that the expression ( void )999 has no effect.